# gstreamer videotestsrc rtp not working

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I have been trying to get gstreamer rtp working on my osx lion I have following:

sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink -vvv
```

receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f50a041e1463000001b24c61766335332e33352e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1613325455, timestamp-offset=(uint)3778351903, seqnum-offset=(uint)5013" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! avdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

but all i get is a green screen on the receiver.  Am i setting up my pipelines incorrectly?

I tried using the tcpserversink and tcpclientsrc as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotesavenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=2 ! tcpserversink  port=5555 -vvv --gst-debug=3

gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=5555 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800f50a041e1463000001b24c61766335332e33352e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)970028597, timestamp-offset=(uint)2609711508, seqnum-offset=(uint)59228" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink --gst-debug=3 -vvv
```

which results in a flickering test source and the following error repeated on the client side:

```
0:00:06.213137000 10134 0x7fab6b051680 ERROR                  libav :0:: Error at MB: 311
0:00:06.214311000 10134 0x7fab6b051680 ERROR                  libav :0:: ac-tex damaged at 19 14
```

can someone construct a test pipeline to output the videotestsrc to mpeg4 video with both a sender and receiver please??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "host" for the udpsink like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 -vvv
```

Comment: Try: gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 udpsrc ! fakesink -v and tell me what you see.

Comment: Hi thanks, the output is:

`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioTestSrc:audiotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1`